# Difference in approaches for the expression `a and b or not a and c`

Tags: php, logic

I want to set a boolean variable that is supposed to be true for `(a && b) || (!a && c)`.

My first idea would be to simply write it down like that:

```
$result = ($a && $b) || (!$a && $c);
```

But would it be in any way better or more time efficient to do something like this:

```
$result = false;
if ( $a ) {
    $result = $b;
} else {
    $result = $c;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any logic behind doing it.

Comment: what does `to set a boolean variable` mean ? To return a boolean value or to return some variable value?

Comment: Perhaps `$a ? $b : $c`?

Comment: @JohnHascall Yes that is just a shortened version of the if-statement approach. But I want to know, why it is better than my first idea.

Comment: Two reasons why it is better: (1) succinctness aids understanding, and (2) as a simple expression it could be used anywhere an expression is allowed, for example: `myfunc($a ? $b : $c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$result = false;                   /* this line has no usefulness */
if ( $a ) {
    $result = $b;
} else {
    $result = $c;
}
```

Is simply a wordier version of:

```
$result = $a ? $b : $c;
```

But both would be subtly different than:

```
$result = ($a && $b) || (!$a && $c);
```

**if** `$a` was something with side effects, because it is potentially evaluated twice in this code.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are checking if both are true OR `a` is false and `c` is true:

```
($a && $b) || (!$a && $c);
```

Over here:

```
$result = false;
if ( $a ) {
    $result = $b;
} else {
    $result = $c;
}
```

You output `c` if `a` is false else `b`

What do you want to exactly do?

You must look for trinary operators: `($a) ? $b : $c;`

Check out the detailed explanation: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator/

Comment: Both snippets should be doing exactly the same thing. Since a, b and c are all booleans the second snippet does not "output" any of these variables but sets the result variable. Look at the first statement: It will be true if $a is true and $b is true. This is done by the if-statement. If a is true, $b will decide. Now if $a is false and $c is true, the result would also be true. That is done be the else-statement. The else-Statement will only be called if $a is false and now $c will decide.

Answer (score 1):

try like below :

$result = ($a==true)?$b;$c

Comment: Yes, but that's basically the same approach as the second snippet. But tell me, why is this any better than the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

with modern CPUs, the time that you gain is lesser than the time of writing this question, even in 1000000 executions, anyway

if you want to assign result:

```
result=a?b:c;
```

if you want to check an if/while:

```
if(a?b:c){
 ...
}
```